# How to update cursor records using WHERE CURRENT OF?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I'm getting "ORA-01410: Invalid ROWID" exception when executing this block. Any ideas why?

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_orders IS
    SELECT * from orders FOR UPDATE OF no;
  v_order_record c_orders%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_orders; 
  LOOP
    FETCH c_orders INTO v_order_record;
    UPDATE orders SET no = 11 WHERE CURRENT OF c_orders;
    EXIT WHEN c_orders%NOTFOUND; 
  END LOOP;  
  CLOSE c_orders; 
END;
```

However, everything works if using FOR IN syntax:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_orders IS
    SELECT * from orders FOR UPDATE OF no;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN c_orders
  LOOP
    UPDATE orders SET no = 11 WHERE CURRENT OF c_orders;
  END LOOP; 
END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `exit when` to before the `update` - you can't update something that doesn't exist.