# Counting records in a table and updating a table using a cursor

Tags: oracle

I have the following tables in Oracle:

```
Teacher
id_teacher (pk)
number_courses

Course
id_course (pk)
id_teacher (fk)
```

I would like to create a cursor that updates the `number_courses` field from the `Teacher` table by counting the courses a teacher has been assigned to. For what I know I should first declare a cursor like this:

```
cursor c_teacher IS
        select id_teacher from teacher;
```

And then do a for loop iterating over the results from this cursor and counting the assigned courses, a draft of my solution is:

```
declare
  countC number(2);
    cursor c_teacher IS
        select id_teacher from teacher;
begin
    for data in c_teacher
    loop
        select count(id_teacher) into countC from Course where id_teacher=data;
        --I can output here with a DMBS_OUTPUT only to see if its working, but
        --I need to use an UPDATE instruction
    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a cursor. (Unless this is a dramatic simplification of the actual problem you are facing. Or this is a poorly thought out homework problem. In which case the secret is [`update where current of`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207379/how-to-update-cursor-records-using-where-current-of))

A single update statement with correlated subquery will do the job:

```
update Teachers T
set number_courses = (select count(*)
    from Courses C
    where C.id_teacher = T.id_teacher);
```

What's likely to be even better, because the values can't get out of synch, is to not store the number of courses in the teachers table and calculate the correct value when needed:

```
alter table Teachers drop column number_courses;

create view Teachers_VW as
select T.id_teacher
    , count(*) as number_courses
from Teachers T
left outer join Courses C on C.id_teacher = T.id_teacher
group by T.id_teacher;
```